# Convert for loop to jax.lax.scan

Tags: python, index-error, jax

How does one convert the following (to accelerate compiling)?
The `for` loop version works with `jax.jit`,

```
import functools
import jax
import jax.numpy as jnp

@functools.partial(jax.jit, static_argnums=0)
def func(n):

    p = 1
    x = jnp.arange(8)
    y = jnp.zeros((n,))

    for idx in range(n):
        y = y.at[idx].set(jnp.sum(x[::p]))
        p = 2*p

    return y

func(2)
# >> Array([28., 12.], dtype=float32)
```

but will return `static start/stop/step` errors when using `scan`

```
import numpy as np

def body(p, xi):

    y = jnp.sum(x[::p])

    p = 2*p

    return p, y

x = jnp.arange(8)

jax.lax.scan(body, 1, np.arange(2))
# >> IndexError: Array slice indices must have static start/stop/step ...
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue here is that within `scan`, the `p` variable represents a dynamic value, meaning that `x[::p]` is a dynamically-sized array, so the operation is not allowed in JAX transformations (see [JAX sharp bits: dynamic shapes](https://jax.readthedocs.io/en/latest/notebooks/Common_Gotchas_in_JAX.html#dynamic-shapes)).

Often in such cases it's possible to replace approaches using dynamically-shaped intermediates with other approaches that compute the same thing using only use static arrays; in this case one thing you might do is replace this problematic line:

```py
jnp.sum(x[::p])
```

with this, which does the same sum using only statically-sized arrays:

```py
jnp.sum(x, where=jnp.arange(len(x)) % p == 0)
```

Using this idea, here's a version of your original function that uses `scan`:

```py
import numpy as np

@functools.partial(jax.jit, static_argnums=0)
def func_scan(n):
    p = 1
    x = jnp.arange(8)
    y = jnp.zeros((n,))

    def body(carry, _):
      idx, y, p = carry
      y = y.at[idx].set(jnp.sum(x, where=jnp.arange(len(x)) % p == 0))
      return (idx + 1, y, 2 * p), None

    (i, y, p), _ = jax.lax.scan(body, (0, y, p), xs=None, length=n)
    return y

func_scan(2)
# Array([28., 12.], dtype=float32)
```

Comment: Thanks Jake. Essentially, the strategy must involve the use of dynamic values passed to scan. It is not possible to designate some arguments as static and concrete.

Comment: Any value passed via `carry` or `xs` is treated as dynamic. If a value doesn't change from iteration to iteration, you can leave it out of the scan body arguments and close over it instead, and can be static. For example, if you used `n` within the body function, it would be static. Because your `p` value changes from iteration to iteration, it cannot be static by definition.